# how to change hover to onclick in angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

i am using css where mouse hover flip flop feature is working but i want this on click to how to achieve this.

```html
<div class="card-flip-front">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   
        <div class="w3-container">
          <div style="margin-left: -15px">
           
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you have hover functionality in the above snippet?

Comment: @G_S css file which use this
.card-flip { position: relative;} .card-flip-front { -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg); z-index: 1;}:hover > .card-flip-front { -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg); transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
}.card-flip-back { -webkit-transform: perspective(600px)rotateY(-179deg);
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-179deg);}:hover> .card-flip-back { -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
 z-index: 2; }

Comment: can you post it aswell? what you are doing on hover? and a code snippet with a working feature on hover would help us

Comment: @G_S i use only css file like:hover > .card-flip-back {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);

  z-index: 2; for IE 9
}

Comment: So you are looking for animations when clicked on that card-flip-front div?

Comment: @G_S  i want flip flop event on ng click featrue in angular so how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

On a rough way, Is this what you are looking for?

Link to [flip flop](http://jsfiddle.net/c3cuncom/)

Handled click and toggled between the required classes.

```
$scope.flipClasses = function() {
    //$scope.todos.push({text:$scope.todoText, done:false});
    if($scope.cardFlipFrontClass == 'card-flip-front flipped'){
    $scope.cardFlipFrontClass =  'card-flip-front';
    }
   else

    $scope.cardFlipFrontClass =  'card-flip-front flipped';

  };
```

I hope this should give you a basic idea on how to fit classes to suit your situation